# Font based icon not centering in Android WebView

Tags: html, css, android-webview, font-face

I'm working on a mobile app, which has some pictures on the screen, and each picture has an associated button on the top right with a heart icon.

The icon is basically a font glyph.

The thing is that the icon and the button look perfect on FF, Chrome, and even IE (I checked on IE 9). The problem is that the icon is not centered in Android's WebView (Android's default browser, or PhoneGap). In the android browser, the icon appears to be right aligned within the button.

You can check out a test page here: http://work.kryptomens.com/Temp/index.html

Try loading this page (on mobile devices) in Chrome, and FF. Then try to see it in Android's default browser. You'll see what I mean.

You can check out the code by viewing the source of the page at the above link.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been fighting very similar issue lately, but unfortunately found no cure yet. It has clearly something to do with font's vertical metrics, and how different OS and browsers handle them. Some theory can be found [here](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/07/14/font-metrics-and-vertical-space-in-css/). 

The thing that made some positive impact for me, was to re-generate the icon font with [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) in expert mode, with `Fix Vertical Metrics` Rendering on.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The blog post was quite educational. However, my main issue is with the icon's horizontal alignment. Do you think fixing the font's vertical metrics will help?

Comment: I regenerated the font as per your recommendation. Like you said, it definitely made a positive impact, but its not a complete cure. Thanks for the recommendation though.